# Swagger UI with put and post endpoint causing UI to crash

Tags: c#

My swagger is not working in my ASP.net core project. It works when I comment out either the put or post action method. I have also tried putting the name of eachpoint to fix the problem but it didnt work. Can anyone tell me how to overcome this issue? Thanks

```
 [HttpPut("{ids}", Name = nameof(Edit))]
   

    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CompanyController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;

        public CompanyController(IMediator mediator)
        {
            _mediator = mediator;
        }
        
        [HttpGet()]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<Company>>> List()
        {
            return await _mediator.Send(new List.Query());
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Unit>> Create(Create.Command command)
        {
            return await _mediator.Send(command);
        }


        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Company>> Details(int id)
        {
            return await _mediator.Send(new Details.Query { Id = id });
        }


        [HttpPut("{ids}", Name = nameof(Edit))]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Unit>> Edit(int ids, Edit.Command command)
        {
            command.Id = ids;
            return await _mediator.Send(command);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I configured swagger in my startup class.

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

           
            services.AddCors(opt =>
            {
                opt.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policy =>
                {
                    policy.AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
                });
            });

            // Register the Swagger generator, defining 1 or more Swagger documents
            **services.AddSwaggerGen();**

            services.AddControllers()
                .AddFluentValidation(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Create>();
                });

            services.AddMediatR(typeof(List.Handler).Assembly);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
         public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
            **app.UseSwagger();

            // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
            // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            });**

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: How did you configure a swagger?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski added how i configured swagger to the question. Thanks

Comment: I noticed your affected APIs are sharing a classname in Create.Command and Edit.Command. Able to try to configure swagger to have fully qualified classes?:

  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56475384/swagger-different-classes-in-different-namespaces-with-same-name-dont-work