Swagger has 500 error with the same named objects but different namespaces
I am using .NET 8 with minimal APIs and a Feature Folder approach.
Features
  Delete
    Handler.cs
    JsonRequest.cs
    JsonResponse.cs
  Get
    Handler.cs
    JsonRequest.cs
    JsonResponse.cs
  Post
    Handler.cs
    JsonRequest.cs
    JsonResponse.cs
  Put
    Handler.cs
    JsonRequest.cs
    JsonResponse.cs

If I leave the naming as shown then Swagger pops a 500 error.  Does not really say why but I've tracked it down to having the same object name as a param yet each object is different.
    public static async Task<IResult> PostUser(HttpContext httpContext, IMediator mediator, [FromBody] Post.JsonRequest jsonRequest)
    {
        var request = new Post.Handler.Request(httpContext, jsonRequest);
        var response = await mediator.Send(request);
        return response.ResultForHttp;
    }

    public static async Task<IResult> PutUser(HttpContext httpContext,IMediator mediator,[FromBody] Put.JsonRequest jsonRequest)
    {
        var request = new Put.Handler.Request(httpContext, jsonRequest);
        var response = await mediator.Send(request);
        return response.ResultForHttp;
    }

    public static async Task<IResult> DeleteUser(HttpContext httpContext, IMediator mediator, [FromBody] Delete.JsonRequest jsonRequest)
    {
        var request = new Delete.Handler.Request(httpContext, jsonRequest);
        var response = await mediator.Send(request);
        return response.ResultForHttp;
    }

If I change the class names to unique names then swagger works as expected:
    public static async Task<IResult> PostUser(HttpContext httpContext, IMediator mediator, [FromBody] Post.PostJsonRequest jsonRequest)
    {...}

    public static async Task<IResult> PutUser(HttpContext httpContext,IMediator mediator,[FromBody] Put.PutJsonRequest jsonRequest)
    {...}

    public static async Task<IResult> DeleteUser(HttpContext httpContext, IMediator mediator, [FromBody] Delete.DeleteJsonRequest jsonRequest)
    {...}

Is there a way to configure swagger to allow for the same named but different objects in a minimal API?
NOTE:  The entire project handles only one resource - Users.
NOTE: Adding the 3 JSON classes to help clarify.
DELETE:
namespace Api.Users.Features.Delete;
public class DeleteJsonRequest : BaseJsonRequest
{
    [JsonPropertyName("channel")] public ChannelDataJson ChannelData { get; set; } = new();
    [JsonPropertyName("userIdentifiers")] public List<string> UserIdentifiers { get; set; } = [];
}

POST:
namespace Api.Users.Features.Post;
public class PostJsonRequest : BaseJsonRequest
{
    [JsonPropertyName("channel")] public ChannelDataJson ChannelData { get; set; } = new();
    [JsonPropertyName("users")] public List<FullUser> Users { get; set; } = [];
}

PUT:
namespace Api.Users.Features.Put;
public class PutJsonRequest : BaseJsonRequest
{
    [JsonPropertyName("channel")] public ChannelDataJson ChannelData { get; set; } = new();
    [JsonPropertyName("users")] public List<FullUser> Users { get; set; } = [];

    [JsonPropertyName("lockAction")] public EnumLockAction Action { get; set; } = EnumLockAction.None;
}

To reiterate: If I change the class names of each of these 3 classes to RequestJson swagger breaks, even though they are all in differing namespaces.

Try using config.CustomSchemaIds(x => x.FullName); in services.AddSwaggerGen.

How does that handle swagger differentiating Post.JsonRequest from Put.JsonRequest or Delete.JsonRequest?  I had to rename the classes to Post.PostJsonRequest, Put.PutJsonRequest and Delete.DeleteJsonRequest

Please have a look at the next answer of a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57665848
